# WooCommerce not sending emails; configured SMTP

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce

I'm using my outlook server to hopefully send order notifications to both the admin and customer through Woocommerce. I installed WP-SMTP plugin to configure the outlook server and sending a test e-mail comes through great. However, when I do an actual order both the customer and the admin do not get emails even though the woocommerce email notifications are set up (as seen below).

[image]

I've even changed the order status to processing, etc.. and the other options but still am not receiving anything. Can anyone give some insight on this matter?

Comment: Does it work fine if you try to bypass the WP-SMTP? And send through the usual wp_mail()?
I assume you have already checked your SPAM folders for the emails you are looking for & they aren't present in there too?

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work sending through regular wp_mail because my email server is different than my webhost. And I've checked the spam folders as well -- nothing!